# How to map/manipulate data in Postman Flows

Tags: postman, postman-flows

I've tried to transform data from API response in **Postman Flows** `evaluate` block using [Postman FQL](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman-flows/flows-query-language/data-manipulation/) but unable to make it work. Here my script written in API tests

```
places.map(place => {
  return {
    id: place['id'], 
    dt: Object.assign({a: 1}, place['data'])
 }
})
```

The code is straight forward, if the place data is null or missing `a`, append that field to the `dt`.

I am able to get the desired field in Postman evaluate but don't know how to append `a` to the `dt`

```
body.{
  'id':id, 
  'dt': data
}
```

[image: Flow evaluate]

How can I do it in Postman Flows' evaluate?

Comment: I have a question, I requested early access in today, how long takes a  time to use it?

Comment: @BenchVue Idk mate, just found it appear in my account at least a few months ago but didn't have time to try it.

Comment: Thanks you very much you are an early adopter. I think most people not yet available to test Flows. It will be quick to address a problem  by your yourself.

Comment: Thanks @BenchVue. I can finally achieve what I need, but not what I expect. Maybe Flows planned to improve in the future. Will post my solution below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was hoping to have access to similar object manipulation methods in FQL as we have in JavaScript, such as merging objects and adding properties. Instead, I have to manually combine objects, which can be challenging as I need to be aware of the number of properties an object has and ensure that properties with null values do not cause any issues.

[image: Flow]